# Error with timestamp in postgres using Spring Data: column $COLUMN_NAME is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type bytea

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Using the following:

Oracle JDK 1.8.0._171

Spring boot 1.5.9-RELEASE

Postgresql 9.6

Postgres driver: 42.2.4

Getting the error from following definition:

Table column: 
`sql
meal_time   TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT NULL`

Entity attribute definition: 
`java
@Column(name = "meal_time", nullable=false)
private Instant mealTime = Instant.now();`

Whenever I try to flush or query the entity throws the error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "meal_time" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I could write a converter for this field but there should be a standard way and it feels like I am missing something as looking around for examples I found very close implementations that actually work.

Comment: Have you tried including `hibernate-java-8` in your dependencies? `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.9` depends on `hibernate-core:5.0.12`, which did not include support for Java 8's Date and Time API types AFAIK (I think it is included in `hibernate-core` for newer Hibernate versions, though)

Comment: @crizzis - thank you for the feedback. Just tried as you suggested but unfortunately same error perists. I will write a converter by now but still looking for a better, standard solution.

Comment: and where have you told your JPA provider to persist the `Instant` as a TIMESTAMP? You haven't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research I've found [this page, Using Java 8 Date and Time classes](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html) from official postgres documentation and changed the property type to be LocalDateTime instead of Instant:

`java
@Column(name = "meal_time", nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime mealTime = LocalDateTime.now();`

This fixed the issue and was an acceptable solution in this specific project.

Answer (score 1):

As @crizzis points out, in Hibernate core module `org.hibernate:hibernate-core` (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core) the Java 8 type mappings, including mappings from/to `java.time.Instant`, are included from version 5.2 and onwards. If using a hibernate-core version prior to 5.1, these type mappings are included in the special module `org.hibernate:hibernate-java8` (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8). Note that this module is empty from version 5.2 (where it was moved to hibernate-core), so I recommend using version 5.1.17.Final, e.g

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.16.Final'
```